# Is it possible to print a windows form from set X,Y coordinates

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, printing, coordinates, printform

I am able to print the entire windows form but the top of the printout is not necessary. Is there a  way to print from specific coordinates i.e X = 0 Y = 50.

This is the code i use to print the entire form.

```
    private void btn_Print_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        printForm1.PrintAction = PrintAction.PrintToPreview;
        printForm1.Print();
    }
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use [DrawToBitmap](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.windows.forms.control.drawtobitmap.aspx) method, to get a screenshot of your form. Then edit a bitmap and send it to printer.